# Android spinner get text after comma

Tags: android, string, spinner, country

In my android application I am using spinner for selecting data.. and I created string array for strings that to be displayed in spinner. I put  all the details in strings folder. I wanted the selected text t be displayed in edit text once the user selected item..

For example : spinner is used to select country codes suppose user selected USA
then the selected text will be like this

United States of America,+001

I don't need t take all the text and display it in edit text. I need only the text after comma, that is +001. So is there any way to get the text after the comma only

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I know this will display all text I want only text that dislpaying after comma

Comment: Can't use use split ? Like this : "text.split(',')[1]" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your text on the comma:

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String[] splited_text = text.split(",");
text = splited_text[1];
```

Comment: text = splited_text[1];

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the text is in a string name `text`. use this:

```
String[] temp = text.split(",")
String code  = temp[1]; //+001 the code after , temp[0] contains the rest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String seperated[] = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().split(",");
text = seperated[1];
```

This will return only "+001".

Answer (score 1):

```
String code = text.substring(text.indexOf(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get string after last comma:

```
        String founded;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*,\\s*(.*)");
        String dd = (String) "Your string, really, really2";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(dd);

        if (m.find()) {
            founded = m.group(1); //returns "really2"
        }
```